# Jira pop-up message

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin

**Hi**

I created a Jira plugin for some customized reports using Java API and now I am looking for a way to add some warnings for the user. What I would like to find is a way to create some pop-ups to display warnings but I don't want to use the MessageBox from Javascript in my .vm file.
Is there any way to create pop-up messages in Jira plugins?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to leverage integrated AUI (Atlassian User Interface) to display good-looking messages.
https://docs.atlassian.com/aui/8.6.0/docs/messages.html

More info about AUI: https://docs.atlassian.com/aui/getting-started.html